# Vue APP When IDM Grab the PDF file get an error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I have a button and then when user Click on it on Chrome the PDF file download automatically with Chrome Download Manager without any problem.

When I Installed Internet Download Manager and Click on Button, IDM handle the download and download it completely but I get an error on Vue app. (PDF download completely and healthy by IDM but the vue app show an unexpected error).

```
<a ref="printElement" download />

const file = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

printElement.setAttribute('href', ${fileURL as string});

nextTick();

printElement.click();

responseEncoding: 'arraybuffer',

responseType: 'arraybuffer',
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGgDQ.png)

I mentioned again that with this error PDF downloaded completely and healthy. How I can fix this error?